# how to take backup to a network share?

Tags: sql-server-2008

when i tried to back up the database to a shared network i am getting the following error can any one help me?

***Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Full_BCK, Line 21 
Cannot open backup device '\prabha\Rajniprabha\SivaBaba2008_Full.bak'. Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105). 
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Full_BCK, Line 21 
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.***

Answer (score 1):

Error 5 means Access denied. Are you sure the user running SQL Server has access to that folder?

Also you seem to be missing the first backslash (which could translate to an access denied error), it should be

```
\\prabha\Rajniprabha\SivaBaba2008_Full.bak
```